# animation-delay works improperly

Tags: html, jquery, css

I am using a CSS animation to get my logo to slide in from off screen. What i'm looking for is the animation gets started with 3s delay right after the page gets loaded but the logo must be hidden at first and then suddenly it comes down slowly from the top of the page after 3s of loading it with the specified animation. what I have here is that you can see the logo when you load the page at the beginning and then after 3s the animation starts working. no one should see the logo at first. it must get appeared after 3s of loading the page. does anybody know what i'm missing here?

This is my CSS:

```
#logo-header {
    height: 240px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    animation:  var(--logo-header-time) ease-in-out 3s 1 logo-header;
}

body {
    font-family: WeHaveSomeFontsHere;
    --nav-load-time: 350ms;
    --names-header-time: 2s;
    --logo-header-time: 1s;
}

@keyframes logo-header {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(-100%);
        display: none;
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get your logo to be hidden until the animation happens, you need the line of code `animation-fill-mode: backwards;` in your `#logo-header`

```
#logo-header {
    height: 240px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    animation:  var(--logo-header-time) ease-in-out 3s 1 logo-header;
    animation-fill-mode: backwards;
}

body {
    font-family: WeHaveSomeFontsHere;
    --nav-load-time: 350ms;
    --names-header-time: 2s;
    --logo-header-time: 1s;
}

@keyframes logo-header {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(-100%);
        display: none;
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
}
```